# How to put return data from .success into another object?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get the return data inside .success.
so I tried this ..

```
.controller('main', function($scope,$http){
    $http({
    method: 'JSONP',
    url: 'someURL'})
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.responseData = data;
    });
    $scope.anotherObj = $scope.responseData;
}
```

Then I realized that the $scope.anotherObj is 'undefined'. What is the easiest way to get the return data out of .success?

Comment: *"What is the easiest way to get the return data out of .success?"* you can't, unless that other place is also waiting for success callback to be called.

Comment: So how I can do it? Should I put all this code into .factory and then call it in the controller? If possible, could you provide me some example please. @KevinB

Comment: No, simply move the line that is outside the success to inside it. Done. Any template that is using `$scope.anotherObj` will automagically update. Though, it likely would be a good idea to use a factory or service for this so that it can be re-used by multiple controllers.

Comment: Oh, yes I see but what if I want to share this data with another controller too? Is that possible? @KevinB

Comment: That's what factories/services are for.